# Retrieving all User Tasks from an Activiti Workflow

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

Hi I am quite new to Activiti, and wanted to see if there is a way to get all the user tasks within an Activiti workflow. I have tried doing this.

```
getTaskService().createTaskQuery()
                .processDefinitionId(processDefinitionId).list();
```

But this does not give me the desired result. It does not return just the User Tasks.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get a specific user all tasks you can use the below code:

```
List<Task> tasks=getTaskService().createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(userid).active().list();
```

but if you want all active tasks use the below code:

```
List<Task> tasks=getTaskService().createTaskQuery().active().list();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but by User Tasks I mean the ones you can drag from the activiti-explorer editor. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method in RepositoryService:
BpmnModel getBpmnModel(String processDefinitionId);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31458825)